# Disable Database Initialization for Entity Framework 4.3

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I'm using EF 4.3.1 and I have 100+ contexts which drives 1 base context. For all contexts I want to disable Database Initialization.

Is it possible to set default behavior for Entity Framework?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just wanted to point out that you should probably reword your question to mention that you need this behavior for multiple contexts. All the provided answers are ok for any given context. Also, you should not use tags in your question title, since it is redundant. I decided not to edit it because I feel you should rephrase it at the same time.

Comment: This question is very old but I have to ask why didn't you just comment out the initializer line in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//Gather all the DbContexts types in the assembly
var allDbContextsTypes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(t => t.BaseType == (typeof(DbContext))).ToList();

foreach (Type dbContextType in allDbContextsTypes)
{
    //Get the SetInitializerMethod
    MethodInfo initializerMethod = typeof(Database).GetMethod("SetInitializer");

    //Make it generic! (Oh yeah)
    MethodInfo dbContextInitializerMethod = initializerMethod.MakeGenericMethod(dbContextType);

    //Invoke the method with null initializer
    dbContextInitializerMethod.Invoke(null, new object[]{null});
}
```

In the end, it gives something like : `Database.SetInitializer<YourDbContext>(null);`
where YourDbContext is the current dbContext type in your loop

Answer (score 2):

`Database.SetInitializer<TContext>` is what you are after. Also passing null to this method should disable initialization.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679461(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: this is not what I looking for because I don't want to edit 100+ entities. when I run this code for base context it does not change anything and creates db.

Comment: If you had the DbInitializer code in all your derived contexts then, no, this wont work because the derived constructor runs AFTER the base constructor so all it would do is turn it off and then back on again.

Answer (score 2):

You can change your **.config* file to disable database initialization.  This is done per context, but maybe it will work for your base context.

```
<contexts>
  <context type=" Blogging.BlogContext, MyAssembly" disableDatabaseInitialization="true" />
</contexts>
```

A much better explanation is given in [EF 4.3 Configuration File Settings](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/01/12/ef-4-3-configuration-file-settings.aspx)

Comment: This doesn't work because code override configuration.